# Pantheon Mail not responsive, stuck on top message

Tags: pantheon-mail

I am having an issue with Pantheon Mail. It is not loading new mail from the server when I open the app. Also, I can scroll between messages in the middle panel, but it never shows me the content for any message except for the first one. The delete button depresses, but does nothing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have got the same issue and its really annoying

Comment: I'f got the same issue as well. It seems that deleted messages are still showing and somehow blocking the app.